# Media type in REST API for validation

Tags: java, validation, rest

I have to write the Rest APIs to perform the CRUD operation on an object say Employee.

```
class Employee {

   String name;

   String id;

}
```

- there can be more fields, for the purpose of example we are considering 2 only.

At the time of create and update there can be lot of validation, like

- employee name and id can't be null.
- Name can't contain more than 40 chars.
- id has only alphabets.

At the time of create, for each validation I have to give proper message to the user. If there are multiple failure on one create operation.  I have to show all the message to the user.

I am looking for a good design solution for this.

Comment: What language? what does this have to do with media types?

Comment: media type means object return by the API API. Content type are JSON and development language is Java. Whe we create and update the Emplyee object it will return us json of newly created object.

Comment: *media type means object return by the API* no, a media type is a two-part identifier for file formats on the Internet. Like `application/json` or `text/html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you asked for a design, I will not take the time to add code to this, but the idea should be something like this:

- Make a data structure that can hold errors. Preferably a HashMap for storing key-value pairs
- For each parameter that you are validation, do the necessary check. If it's fine, all good. If it's erroneous in some way, add an entry to the HashMap describing the error.
- After the validation, check if the HashMap has any entries. If it does, there are errors and you should not create a User but return the error response. If it doesn't then you can create the User and return a success response.

The data structure could look like this (in JSON)

```
{
    "success": "no",
    "error": "validation_failed",
    "validation_errors": [
        {"name": "too long"},
        {"id": "invalid format, must be String"}
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, till now this is the right design as I am thinking which is not correct. I understand what you want to thinking. Will ping you if I will have any other query in this. I appreciate your quick and pertinent answer.